# Extract a part of fasta sequence based on bp coordinates

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I have a huge fasta file, but I need to extract only a part of it, If I know the start and end base pair coordinate of my sequence. Also, it should be in fasta format with the length of 60 bp per line.This is my try, please let me know if looks OK and any suggestions to improve it are welcome.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

inFile = open('full_chr.fa','r')
fw=open("part.fa",'w')
line_width = 60
for record in SeqIO.parse(inFile,'fasta'):
    fw.write(">" + record.id + "\n")
    fww = (str(record.seq[600130000:602000000]) + '\n')
    for i in xrange(0,len(fww),line_width):
        fw.write(str(fww[i:i+line_width]) + '\n')
fw.close()
```

Comment: fasta format is not restricted to a length of 60bp per line

Comment: i recommended bedtools getfasta http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
from Bio import SeqIO


record = SeqIO.read("Chromosome.fas", "fasta")

with open("output.fas", "w") as out:
    SeqIO.write(record[100:500], out, "fasta")
```

The `SeqIO.write` already uses a 60 character length wrapping. If you want to manipulate the line wrap use the `FastaWriter` object. This is an example for 80 bp lines:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO import FastaWriter


record = SeqIO.read("Chromosome.fas", "fasta")

with open("output.fas", "w") as out:
    writer = FastaWriter(out, wrap=80)
    writer.write_header()
    writer.write_record(record[100:500])
    writer.write_footer()
```

Comment: my script above gives the same output as yours, but yours is simpler and nicer ;) thanks